# Computing interest

Tags: javascript, math

I started studying javascript last weekend, I started from basics and now I'm in arithmetic. I tried to compute the interest but my code doesn't do anything. I'm not sure where's the error is, please help me with this. Thanks!

I tried to search for some codes that are relevant to my problem but it was so difficult to understand.

```
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
    var days = document.getElementById('days').value;
    var principal = amount;
    var interest = (interest_rate * .01);
    var payment = ((amount * interest) * days + principal) .toFixed(2);
```

I wanted to display the payment amount, that's all. Thanks! :)

Comment: What exactly is wrong? What error did you see?

Comment: assuming the interest rate is annual, you will want to divide days by 365 (not accounting for compounding, otherwise you'll need P(1+r/n)^(nt)

Comment: You have a space between ) and .toFixed(2); Also you are not showing any output statement such as window.alert(payment);
or document.write(payment);

Answer (score 2):

Input values are strings. You need to turn them into a number in order to perform math operations, using `parseFloat` for numbers with decimals or `parseInt` for whole numbers.

(I guessed at which are whole numbers and which are decimals.)

```
var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);
var interest_rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById('interest_rate').value);
var days = parseInt(document.getElementById('days').value);
var principal = amount;
var interest = (interest_rate * .01);
var payment = ((amount * interest) * days + principal) .toFixed(2);
```

Just so you are aware, `toFixed()` will return a string. It’s fine for displaying to the user, but don’t try to do any math with it.

Comment: I used <input type="number">in body, does I need to have also a parseFloat in js?

Comment: @Civ Yup! That just restricts the values to only allow numbers to be entered, but the values are still strings and must be converted to a numeric type to do math with them. It is kind of odd, huh?